# Updating raster of mxd file using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, mxd

Using ArcGIS 10 wanted to update the raster file in a mxd file using python. for example, i created a.mxd which contains b.tif file in it. now, i obtained c.tif and want to update the a.mxd, i.e. want to delete b.tif and add c.tif, or overwrite b.tif with c.tif

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\data\a.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

updateLyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]
sourceLyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(arcpy.Raster(r"C:\data\c.tif"))

arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, updateLyr, sourceLyr, True)

del mxd
```

i started as above, but i think that i am not getting most of the things correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want `replaceDataSource` instead of `UpdateLayer`. Update uses a template, the *sourceLyr*, and applies its properties (data path, symbology, etc.) to the layer-to-be-updated whereas you only want to change the data path/filename.

See [Updating and fixing data sources with arcpy.mapping](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Updating_and_fixing_data_sources_with_arcpy_mapping/00s30000004p000000/) in the Esri docs for more detail, and [Changing data source path involving feature dataset in *.lyr files using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6884/change-data-source-path-in-lyr-files-in-arcgis-10) here on GIS.se for some quirky behaviour to be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Create a layer file consisting of your new tif, named 'c.lyr' and place it in the same directory (i.e. c:\data\c.lyr)
Then run this inside the map document:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
        for refLayer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*b.tif", df):
                mosaic = arcpy.mapping.Layer(u'C:\\data\\c.lyr')
                arcpy.mapping.InsertLayer(df, refLayer, mosaic, "BEFORE")
                mosaic.visible = refLayer.visible
                mosaic.brightness = refLayer.brightness
                mosaic.contrast = refLayer.contrast
                mosaic.transparency = refLayer.transparency
                mosaic.name = refLayer.name
                arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, refLayer)
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
del mxd, df
try:
        del refLayer, mosaic
except:
        pass
finally:
        print u'TIF updated!'
```

Or if you prefer a function:

```
def UpdateTIF(mxd, old, new):
#mxd: path to mxd to update
#old: wildcard matching pattern for the old source
#new: layer file referencing new source
        import arcpy
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd)
        for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
                for refLayer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, old, df):
                        mosaic = arcpy.mapping.Layer(new)
                        arcpy.mapping.InsertLayer(df, refLayer, mosaic, "BEFORE")
                        mosaic.visible = refLayer.visible
                        mosaic.brightness = refLayer.brightness
                        mosaic.contrast = refLayer.contrast
                        mosaic.transparency = refLayer.transparency
                        mosaic.name = refLayer.name
                        arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, refLayer)
        del mxd, df
        try:
                del refLayer, mosaic
        except:
                pass
        finally:
                print u'TIF updated!'
```

Execute this with a call like:

```
UpdateTIF('C:\\data\\a.mxd', '*b.tif', 'C:\\data\\c.lyr')
```